# Facebook Socialite, Login not working as expected (redirect to website fails) - Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, facebook, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-socialite

Facebook Registration works fine and users are redirected to the website but when users try to log-in using their FB account then it does not seem to work, that is, users are not redirected to the website instead loads facebook.com .

I checked the url before facebook asks user to enter fb password and it seems like permission denied is shown as below, but not sure what does that mean?:

```
callback%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied
```

I have added https which I thought could be the cause of error but then so many websites still use fb login successfully even when they don't have SSL (https). Also, SSL (https) does not seem to resolve the issue.

I am not sure how to debug this issue because not sure what is causing this, Laravel Socialite is straight-forward. Other Socialite Login I tried for example: Google+ seems to work just fine.

Any help is appreciated.

If You would like to see any part of the code, let me know in the comment.

Comment: You should check initial request to facebook. Maybe the callback URL you are giving to facebook is not valid?